# Android, clicking on notification group

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a group of notifications in Android App.
I need my application to know if the app was opened when the user clicked on the notification. 
I have used a pending intent and it works brilliantly. But how can I check if the **user has clicked on the notification group?** It shows no links, no notifications sounds, nothing. I found no information in the documentation. Please help.[image]

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: @VitaliyA I'm looking for a solution too

Comment: Solved it by changing notification structure. Usualy notification may contain 2 parts: "notification" and "data". So if you want to handle everything by yourself, just remove the "notification" part.  In this case you get full controll on notifications  when app in background or foreground. Otherwise, firebase will handle all background notifications by it self.

Comment: @VitaliyA It doesn't sound like a solution to the question. I already receive that _data_ type notifications & clicking on a group of notifications leads to restarting the Activity.

Answer (score -2):

You can add flag in intent like **isFromNotification** boolean and then pass that intent to pending intent and then notify user.

Now in activity check intent has this parameter then the user has come from notification. 
(simple like that)

**Sample code**

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);

notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

String channel_Id = "app_channel_01";

notificationIntent.putExtra(AppConstants.INTENTDATA.ISFROMNOTIFICATION,
        true);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyApplication.getInstance(),
            0, notificationIntent,
            0);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyApplication.getInstance(), channel_Id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setColor(MyApplication.getInstance().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white))
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

NotificationManager notificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) MyApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

    // Create or update.
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channel_Id,
        "General Notifications",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: How's that related to determination of whether the user taps on a single notification or a notification group?